# PHP save array for different instances of a script

Tags: php

My PHP script are triggered via POST from different sources.
There is a array, where elements are added and deleted.

I save this array with

```
$jsonString = json_encode($curList);
file_put_contents("curList.obj", $jsonString);
```

and read it with

```
$stringified1 = file_get_contents("curList.obj") ?: '';
$curList = json_decode($stringified1, true) ?: [];
```

This works usually fine. But now I got in trouble, because several instances are running at the same time and read and write the array in the same time period. This creates problems, because some information are going lost.

It is possible to make sure, that another instance has to be wait, until the read and update of the file is finished?

Or is it possible that only one instance of the script is running at the same time, without a POST get lost?

Comment: You want some sort of persistent storage like a database. You've already discovered  some of the problems with using an in-memory datastructure or a file on the file system.

Comment: Easy way - create file curList.lock near when you need "lock" operations and delete after operation. Than check - if file created - don't do anything.

Comment: How are these instances started? By which criteria should the data get shared between different calls?

Comment: @NicoHaase the instances are started by POST messages and should be a list of active processes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Maksim I found the following solution:

```
        $file = "curList.obj";
        $lock = "curList.lock";
        while(true){
            if(!file_exists($lock)){
                $fHandle = fopen($lock, 'x');
                if($fHandle != false)
                    break;
            } 
            usleep(20);
        }
        $stringified1 = file_get_contents("curList.obj") ?: '';
        $curList = json_decode($stringified1, true) ?: [];
        $curList[] = $_POST;
    // save array
        $jsonString = json_encode($curList);
        file_put_contents("curList.obj", $jsonString); 
    // release lock handle and delete lock
        fclose($fHandle);
        unlink($lock);
```

Why this solution.

I am using IIS 10 and there is a problem with IIS and `flock`. Therefore I build a kind of wrapper around the read and write of the data update.
It is an additional `curList.lock` file.

First I check if the file exists, if not I create it with `fopen($lock, 'x')`. The option 'x' only creates the file if it not already exists. Otherwise it will fail and the routine is stil in the `while` loop, until it get an access.

Answer (score 0):

try use [Session](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) in your project. With **Sessions** you can temporary save different data without conflicts.
This information storage is unique to the user, but is not stored forever

Comment: In my case it is not possible to use `$_SESSION`, because sessions working only for a specific `session`, if I am right. But in my case I need a `POOL` where all `sessions` have access for.